# How to call a function when shadowbox finished to open

Tags: jquery, html, shadowbox

i need to call a function when shadowbox is opened and displayed in my page.
I try this:

```
Shadowbox.open({
    content:    contentD,
    player:     "html",
    title:      "Pubblicazione annunci in corso...",
    height:     350,
    width:      350,
    options: { 
            modal:   true,
            onOpen: myOpen
    }
});

function myOpen(){
   alert('ok');
}
```

My problem is that `alert('ok')` is shown before shadowbox is displayed, what can i do? can someone help me?

Comment: unfortunately there're not other suitable hooks and the author didn't provided the original source in the package, so it's difficult to debug the code. - dannazione! :|

Comment: Have you tried to set timeout for alert like `setTimeout(function() { alert('ok'); }, 1);`?

Comment: @VisioN, it doesn't works.. alert message is shown before shadowbox is displayed..

Comment: @F.Calderan, the source for Shadowbox v3.0.3 is on [gitHub](https://github.com/mjijackson/shadowbox/tree/v3.0.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change onOpen by onClose ;)

```
Shadowbox.open({
    content:    contentD,
    player:     "html",
    title:      "Pubblicazione annunci in corso...",
    height:     350,
    width:      350,
    options: { 
            modal:   true,
            onClose: myOpen
    }
});
```

Comment: i try onFinish and the result is what i need! thanks so much! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)